# ANTLR4 get parse tree for scala code, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: scala, antlr4

I am trying to parse a simple scala expression:
`val a = 4 + 5`
using ANTLR 4.

However, whenever I run it, I get the error:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'val a = 4 + 5' expecting {<EOF>, 'implicit', 'lazy', 'case', '@', 'override', 'abstract', 'final', 'sealed', 'private', 'protected', 'import', 'class', 'trait', 'package', ';'}
```

Here is my code:

```
object AntlrMain {

    val v = "val a = 4 + 5"

    val stream = new ANTLRInputStream(v)

    val lexer = new ScalaLexer(stream)

    val tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer)

    val parser = new ScalaParser(tokens)

    val tree: ParseTree = parser.compilationUnit()

}
```

ScalaLexer and ScalaParser have been generated from the scala grammar located here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/scala/Scala.g4

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After sepp2k's comment, I tried to change val v into the following:

```
val v = "object Test { def a(): Int = 4 + 5 }"
```

but the same error persists. 
As for the recommendation to use blockStat() - it works for the previous value of v.

Answer (score 1):

`val a = 4 + 5` isn't a valid Scala file. A `val` needs to be inside a `class`, `trait` or `object` (or inside a `def` inside one of those). The error message gives you the list of keywords that you may use a the top level or a file.

If you want to be able to parse `val` definitions on their own, you should parse a different rule than `compilationUnit`. If you're trying to implement something like a REPL, `blockStat` might make sense, which includes anything that can appear as a statement in a block (like a local definition or an expression).

---

As for why it doesn't work with `object`: Apparently the grammar only allows `object` if it's preceded by `case` (you'll note that `object` does not appear in the list of initially expected tokens). If we look inside the grammar, we find this:

```
tmplDef
   : 'case'? 'class' classDef
   | 'case' 'object' objectDef
   | 'trait' traitDef
;
```

So the `case` keyword is optional before class definitions, but required before object definitions.

This is clearly a bug in the grammar. In the real Scala language `case` is optional before both.

Comment: First, thank you for your time. Second, I took a look at the grammar... I noticed that, but the same error still persists... line 2:0 mismatched input 'case object HelloWorld {' expecting {<EOF>, 'implicit', 'lazy', 'case', '@', 'override', 'abstract', 'final', 'sealed', 'private', 'protected', 'import', 'class', 'trait', 'package', ';'}

Comment: @Marin Hm, it seems like the grammar is more fundamentally broken than just the missing `?`, but I don't see the other mistake(s) right now. Your input is valid though - it's the grammar that's the problem.